# Double Rainbow Explained?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel

Look at the pretty double rainbow:

[image]

While a single rainbow is a bridge to Asgard in Marvel's Thor, what is a double rainbow?

Comment: ...two bridges?

Comment: Not all rainbows a Bifrost, afaik

Comment: The bridge to Bifrost looks like a rainbow in Asgard. On Earth all you see is that crop-circle pattern.

Comment: Also, technically there are *always* two rainbows, just typically the second one is too faint to see.

Comment: This is an entirely different question than the one you originally asked; please don't do that. Your edit invalidates the current answer. Please ask a new question instead.

Comment: I will back Mike up on this, just so you don't think he is only saying this because he was the one who answered...

Comment: In general, having good answers to bad questions is not seen as a bad thing, but I see your point about being associated with a question that's not valuable. I believe, if you "flag" your question for moderator attention you can ask to have your user disassociated from it but I'm not 100% sure how it works.

Answer (score 10):

Rainbows are not bridges to Asgard in *Thor*, the movie, nor in the *Thor* comics.

The Bifrost Bridge is a bridge between Midgard and Asgard that *looks like* a rainbow, because it was designed that way. In the movies, the "rainbow bridge" is just a bridge from the city out to the Bifrost room, and the Bifrost itself is some kind of teleport device. In the comics, it's the name of the actual bridge that you walk over.

Other rainbows, single or double, are just rainbows.